# How to close ploygon infowindow on hover of map marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing google map which is having set of polygons as state boundary and collection markers as a city on polygon and when i am hovering on polygon/state then show some info.

My Question is that how can I close infowindow of marker/city when hover on polygon/state vice-versa.

`Fiddle is here:` [Map Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/hareshpatel/7f744bx8/10/)

Comment: Add some code to your question that demonstrates what you've done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an event listener on the marker and/or polygon:

```
marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.close();
});
```

So when they hover over the marker, i.e. 'mouseover', you close the infowindow.  Without seeing any of your code so far, I assume you have a variable `marker` and `infowindow` that you can access.

Alternatively, you may want to completely remove the infowindow:

```
infowindow.setMap(null);
```

**Update:** ok, now you've at least linked to some of your code, what you probably want to do is close the infowindow when you hover over the polygon, and the stateInfowindow when you hover over the marker.  Something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover', (function(marker){ 
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(find_city);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        stateinfoWindow.close();
    };
  })(marker,infowindow));
```

And:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'mouseover', function (e) {              
    stateinfoWindow.setContent("State");
    stateinfoWindow.open(map);
    infowindow.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but still not working....Can you refer above fiddle link?

Comment: @HareshKumar see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks duncan code is worked for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `polygon` and `infoWindow` declared as the variables you need.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon,"mouseover",function(){
 infowindow.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering....actually there are multiple infowindow for marker and polygon and what i need is that when i hover on marker infowind. of polygon should hide and when hover on polygon infowindow of marker should hide...

Comment: hmm, I see. Can you please put some code in a JSFiddle or something?